# get children of dropped element

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag

I have a draggable and droppable like this

```
$(".element-container [data-PB-element]").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    refreshPositions: true,
    scroll: false,
    zIndex: "100"
});

/* drop */
$("#page-canvas").droppable({
    accept: "[data-PB-element]",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(target);
    }
});
```

What i want to do is select the child elements of the div that was dropped. Not the original element, but the one that was dropped within the #page-canvas container. I want to select the children of that dropped element.

Comment: Surely, with `helper: "clone"` the original element is already cloned so you don't need to clone again with `$(ui.draggable).clone()`? `ui.draggable` is the clone.

Comment: The way i do that is by using (connectWith) -- http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith -- which makes the droppable know what was dropped into it. I don't have multiple items to get in my div as i'm dropping pictures so you will need to find a way to get the child elements. Anyway here is site with an example on how to grab whats has been dropped. It uses Cookies to store but i think you change that. --- http://devheart.org/examples/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/2-saving-and-loading-items/index.html